Web Site SideBar Content
When I click on one of the options in the SideBar, I want the content related to it to open on the right side.
I wrote the code below, but even though I reach the "http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin_panel_menu/A" page, SideBar appears, but the text in contentA.html does not appear. How can I fix this?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/admin_panel.css">
    <title>Admin Paneli</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar içeriği -->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('admin_panel_menu', panel_id='A') }}"> A</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('admin_panel', panel_id='B') }}"> B</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('admin_panel', panel_id='C') }}"> C</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <!-- İçerik gösterilecek alan -->
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

@app.route("/admin_panel")
def admin_panel():
    return render_template("admin_panel.html")

@app.route('/admin_panel_menu/<panel_id>')
def admin_panel_menu(panel_id):
    # content_id'ye göre ilgili içeriği gönder
    if panel_id == 'A':
        return render_template('contentA.html')
    else:
        # Hata durumunda başka bir sayfaya yönlendirme yapılabilir
        return redirect('/gadmin')

I would be happy if you help

Pl check my answer. I got the required output

Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title says nothing about the problem except that it occurs in the sidebar component of a website.

Here the issue is: if panel_id == 'A', You have mentioned in the python file. But when you mentioned <a href="{{ url_for('admin_panel_menu', panel_id='A') }}"> A</a> in your html file. But where the python's panel_id and the html panel_id are mapped?. So this is how you should do. Just with the url "http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin_panel_menu/A", this code will work as expected. In case if the panel_id is provided from HTML input, you should
create a form in html, the forms args should be received in python's file.
HTML(contentA.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/admin_panel.css">
    <title>Admin Paneli</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar içeriği -->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('admin_panel_menu', panel_id='panel_id') }}"> A</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('admin_panel_menu', panel_id='panel_id') }}"> B</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="{{ 'admin_panel_menu', panel_id='panel_id') }}"> C</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <!-- İçerik gösterilecek alan -->
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

PYTHON FILE
from flask import \
Flask as fl, \
render_template as tmp, \
redirect as rd, \
url_for as url, \
request as rq


app = fl(__name__)

@app.route("/admin_panel")
def admin_panel():
    return tmp("admin_panel.html")
    


@app.route('/admin_panel_menu/<panel_id>')
def admin_panel_menu(panel_id):
    # content_id'ye göre ilgili içeriği gönder
    panel_ids = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    htmls = ['contentA.html', 'contentB.html', 'contentC.html']
    for i in range(len(panel_ids)):
        if panel_id == panel_ids[i]:
            return tmp(htmls[i], panel_id = panel_id)
        else:
            return rd('/gadmin')
    
  
        
if __name__ == '__main__' : app.run()

